# Reactstrap - Align navbar items to left and right

Tags: css, reactjs, reactstrap

I currently have a navbar that has site navigation to the left and login/register/search to the right. When I add a button with an image, the layout of the navbar goes wrong and I cannot solve it. The elements that should be to the right, are aligning more the the middle.

This is my JSX:

```
<Navbar className="custNav navbar-inverse bg-primary" expand="md"> 
      <NavbarBrand className='custNav' href="/">Brand</NavbarBrand>
      <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
      <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
          <Nav className='mr-auto' navbar>
              <NavItem className='custNav'>
                  <NavLink className='custNav' href="/comments">Home</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem className='custNav'>
                  <NavLink className='custNav' href="/report">About Us</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                  <NavLink className='custNav' href="/report">Contact Us</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
          </Nav>

          <Nav className='rightNav ml-auto' navbar>
              <NavItem className=' custNav'>
                  <NavLink className='custNav' href="/comments">Login</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem className='custNav'>
                  <NavLink className='custNav' href="/report">Signup</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <FormGroup className='m-auto'>
                  <Input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search" />
              </FormGroup>
              <Button className='searchBTN'><img className='btnIMG' src={searchIMG} alt=''/></Button>
          </Nav>
      </Collapse>
  </Navbar>
```

My CSS:

```
body{
  flex: 1;
}

.custNav{
  background-color: #d4452d !important; 
  color: #f1f2ed !important;
}

.searchNav{
  justify-content: center !important;
  align-items: flex-start !important;
}

.searchBTN{
  background-color: #d4452d !important; 
  color: #f1f2ed !important;
  border-color: #d4452d;
  width: 5%;
  height: 5%;
}

.btnIMG{
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

When I inspected the element, it appears to be the `formgroup` that is taking up all the room between the search button and the signup button.